# Data Comparison in R

Tags: r, dataset

I have to compare two data sets to make sure that they are identical. They are massive data sets with millions of data points. Is this possible in R and if so how would I go about that? I am brand new to R with very limited capabilities.

Comment: If you want to compare if the two datasets are **identical** than the simplest way to go is just take the two files, and check if they have the same hashes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function)...

Comment: @Tim Thank you for the usefull comment which shows, that there are alternatives to brute force comparison and so this question is not only about how to do things in R.

Comment: How identical? What if the only difference between the two files is that two floats differ in their 20th decimal?

Comment: "Identical" in terms of *physical storage* or in terms of *logical contents*?  For instance, two relational tables are logically identical even when their records and fields are arbitrarily reordered.

Comment: Identical as in having the same exact numbers and information. As in item #25 in data set A is the same as item #25 in data set B. We are testing a new model and need to see if the results match up with the current model to make sure it works.

Comment: Do you care about field names?  Are these data sets just simple tables or are they perhaps relational or networked databases?

Comment: Simple tables and the field names are helpful but not vital

Answer (score 0):

Consider a data.frame x and a data.frame y identical but a data.frame z not identical, like in this example. Than the '==' operator and the all() function will test one against the other.

```
> x <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5), c(1,1,1,1,1))
> y <- x
> z <- data.frame(c(2,2,3,4,5), c(1,1,1,1,1))
> 
> all(x==y)
[1] TRUE
> 
> all(x==z)
[1] FALSE
```

This ist brute force, but even with millions of data points, this should run within seconds. If you don't do this over and over and over again, this should suffice. For very large data sets you may run into trouble with memory allocation faster than computing time. For my personal taste that would be the point to Change horses and try something different than R.

Comment: (1) This approach implements a very strict sense of "identical".  (2) However, it does not distinguish two dataframes that have different rownames or field names!  In effect, it is comparing *internally stored values* of an `R` representation of data, but it might or might not be evaluating "identicality" correctly.

Comment: `d = data.frame(pressure = c(2,5,7,8), altitude = c(50,74,44,33)); rownames(d) = c("Gadget1", "Gadget2", "Gadget3", "Gadget4")` and `d.prime = data.frame(no.problems = c(2,5,7,8), time = c(50,74,44,33));
rownames(d.prime) = c("Student1", "Student2", "Student3", "Student4")`. Now  `all(d==d.prime) #TRUE; identical(d,d.prime) #FALSE`. Just to illustrate @whuber comment.

Comment: @whuber I'd have thought this approach could work, with a little data cleaning first to resolve the problems you mention, if needed. Perhaps the OP can provide an `str(dataframe)` for each dataset in an edit.

Comment: Based on comments to the question it's beginning to look like your solution may be on target. There's also a possibility the problem is much simpler than it sounds (that is, it's just matching two streams of output from some model).  Let's wait and see.